# Server Error when making GET request in Spring 3

Tags: hibernate, rest, spring-mvc

I am working on a Spring 3 project and trying to write RESTful services.

I have problems with getting the object list from the server. Here is the server code:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/getRestItemList", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView getRestItemList() {

    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);

    HttpEntity<String> entity = new HttpEntity<String>(headers);
    RestItemCollection itemList = new RestItemCollection();

    try {
        ResponseEntity<RestItemCollection> forObject = restTemplate.exchange("http://localhost:3080/SOHOV01R01C01/getRestItemList",
                HttpMethod.GET, entity,
                RestItemCollection.class);


        itemList = forObject.getBody();



    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

And the client code:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/getRestItemList", headers = "Accept=application/xml, application/json")
public @ResponseBody
List<RestItem> getRestItemList() {

    List<RestItem> itemList = restManService.getRestItemList();

    return itemList;
}
```

When I debug, I can get the object list in the server side. But when it is being sent, some problem raises.

Where am I wrong?

Comment: Wouldn't it make sense to tell us what the error/problem is?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What i understand  getRestItemList() expected to return json,İf so you should annotate this metod with  @ResponseBody (this annotation tell spring to return result as json and not try to solve a view) .In fact   the client code:   looks right but  server code meaningless.